# php encoding issue htmlentities

Tags: php, encoding

I have user input and use htmlentities() to convert all entities.
However, there seems to be some bug. When I type in

```
ääää öööö üüüü ääää
```

I get

```
&Atilde;&curren;&Atilde;&curren;&Atilde;&curren;&Atilde;&curren; &Atilde;&para;&Atilde;&para;&Atilde;&para;&Atilde;&para; &Atilde;&frac14;&Atilde;&frac14;&Atilde;&frac14;&Atilde;&frac14; &Atilde;&curren;&Atilde;&curren;&Atilde;&curren;&Atilde;&curren;
```

Which looks like this

Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤ Ã¶Ã¶Ã¶Ã¶ Ã¼Ã¼Ã¼Ã¼ Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤

What am I doing wrong? The code is really only this:

```
$post=htmlentities($post);
```

EDIT 1

Here is some more code that I use for formatting purposes (there are some helpful functions it them):

```
    //Secure with htmlentities (mysql_real_escape_string() comes later)
    $post=htmlentities($post);

    //Strip obsolete white spaces
    $post = preg_replace("/ +/", " ", $post);

    //Detect links
    $pattern_url='~(?>[a-z+]{2,}://|www\.)(?:[a-z0-9]+(?:\.[a-z0-9]+)?@)?(?:(?:[a-z](?:[a-z0-9]|(?<!-)-)*[a-z0-9])(?:\.[a-z](?:[a-z0-9]|(?<!-)-)*[a-z0-9])+|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))(?:/[^\\/:?*"<>|\n]*[a-z0-9])*/?(?:\?[a-z0-9_.%]+(?:=[a-z0-9_.%:/+-]*)?(?:&[a-z0-9_.%]+(?:=[a-z0-9_.%:/+-]*)?)*)?(?:#[a-z0-9_%.]+)?~i';
    preg_match_all($pattern_url, $post, $matches); 
    for ($i=0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++)
    {
        if(substr($matches[0][$i],0,4)=='www.')
        $post = str_replace($matches[0][$i],'http://'.$matches[0][$i],$post);
    }
    $post = preg_replace($pattern_url,'<a target="_blank" href="\\0">\\0</a>',$post);

    //Keep line breaks (more than one will be stripped above)
    $post=nl2br($post);

    //Remove more than one linebreak
    $post=preg_replace("/(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/", "<br/>", $post);

    //Secure with mysql_real_escape_string()
    $post=mysql_real_escape_string($post);
```

Comment: When you say "really only this" can you share the rest of it? I don't see anything wrong with your PHP so the problem may lie somewhere else.

Comment: @stevether Please see questions edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must manually specify the encoding (`UTF-8`) for [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
echo htmlentities("ääää öööö üüüü ääää", null, "UTF-8");
```

Output:

```
ääää öööö üüüü ääää
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I needed. What does the parameter null do? And do you maybe know why I needed this? I usually just use htmlemtities('string') without any additional params and it normally works fine.

Comment: It just says use the default for the second argument. args 2 and 3 are optional, but if you want to specify the 3rd arg, you have to specify the 2nd. would be equivalent to `htmlentities("string", ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8")`

Answer (score 2):

it is important that 3th parameter of htmlentities matches the character set that uses the post.  I supouse, you are NOT submiting utf8, as it is the default in htmlentities

in PHP

```
 $post = htmlentities ( $post, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1')  // or whatever
```

in Form

```
 <form action="your.php" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

anyway, actualy I recommend you to use utf8