# avoid html escape character in php

Tags: php, html, html-escape-characters

I am trying to make an api call using `PHP`. One of the parameters is currency

My API call goes like

```
<?php 
$call=".....&currency=USD&......."; 
$response = hash_call("Pay", $call);
?>
```

But if I print the call, it prints out as

```
....¤cy=USD&.......
```

I checked and found out that `&curren is for ¤`

**Edit:**
I tried urlencode, and htmlentities. While I hope to get &currency in the source, I am getting %26currency , & amp;currency respectively.

I want to encode '&currency', such that the browser does not convert &curren to  ¤. 
Thanks

Comment: You're seeing something else. Add more details.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams If I echo the API string, It prints the &curren to ¤ . But If I look at the HTML source, it looks fine. So I think I am looking at the right thing. What details can I add?

Comment: Replace `&curren` with `&amp;curren;`.  That's not programmatic, but it will do the job temporarily.

Comment: Shouldn't this only be an issue for output? Not with the actually call/response…

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams  Your solution physically does the job, but the API shows an error, saying Invalid request, and gives an error code coressponding to the currency part. :( Do you know about  htmlentities? Is it something I can use here? sorry I am not well versed with this.

Comment: I've been researching it for the past 15 minutes, as it seems like an odd issue, and the best I can recommend is guess-and-check it by calling `htmlentities` on $call in one test and `urlencode` in another.

Comment: @Jason McCreary Well, I am not sure. Apparently, if I use Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's solution, the response (error code)changes from " user does not have permission" to "invalid request". I am thinking it is causing an issue in the call itself, but Am I sure? No. trying to cross out the odds.

Comment: @Vulcan I guess I replied to the wrong person. 4th comment from me was addressed to you, Vulcan. Thanks for the suggestion. I will do the guess-and-check approach.

Comment: @aVC No worries, I noticed that you were replying to me.  If you find a solution, don't forget to post it as an answer and set it as accepted.

Comment: @Vulcan Defintely. Here is an update. I tried out the guess and check.

with urlencode, I get %26currency when i echo as well as in source.

with htmlentities, I get &currency on echo, but source looks like &amp;currency.

what I need is &currency both when I echo and view source. :( No luck so far.

Comment: Why are you trying to encode it. You said earlier " If I look at the HTML source, it looks fine.". So, it's fine.. don't worry about what the browser does to it when displaying it back to you (ie wrap in htmlentities ONLY IF YOU WANT TO DISPLAY IN THE BROWSER). The stuff you see in source is what you want sent.

Comment: @Hamish I agree. The problem is the API is getting rejected. Trying to find out the cause, I came across the &curren issue. if I tweak around to give &amp;currency in the source, the error code changes to show me that the request is invalid because of the currency part. This to me is indicative that when the API server is translating the call, it is facing the same issue. 

Again, I wish you were right, but the results are not in favor yet.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538929/php-encoding-issue-htmlentities

I solved the same problem here. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP isn't converting anything.

The *browser* is converting `&current` to `¤t` for display purposes. If you want to see what `$call` is **in the browser** then you will need to wrap it with `htmlentities`, but that specifically encodes characters so that the original `$call` is displayed in the browser.

However, you should not do anything to the string `$call` before passing it to `hash_call`.

Remember, there is a big difference between a raw string and what the browser displays.

Comment: True for most practical purposes but unfortunately not working here.   Why so: I did a test. &Current will be shown as &Current itself in browser. So,  If I use $call="...&Currency=USD&...", the error code says 'currency' parameter cannot be null. So I guess the server is finding the same issue with translation.

Comment: That's a huge assumption, and likely incorrect. Is there documentation on the service you are trying to call?

Comment: Yes, I think I am getting the same Idea as well. The interpretation may not be the issue. Thanks for the help.