# How should I use htmlentities to display utf ó (not Ã³)

Tags: php, email, encoding, html-email

I'm writing a small newsletter in PHP

I'm using PHP's `htmlentities($str)` so I'll have no problems with encoding in client's email.

This `$str` is coming out of mysql.

I see `Ã³` when it's supposed to be a `ó` in the client.

I'm also writing some text in the newsletter where I `echo "&oacute;";` and I see it in the client as `ó`.

Then I suppose that I have to make some treatment to `$str` before appliyng the `htmlentities` but I don't understand what should I do.

How can I know what is wrong with (what treatment should I do to) `$str`?

Comment: just output your page with UTF-8 encoding, and you won't need to worry about any of this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solves the issue

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10539209/912450

```
//You must manually specify the encoding (UTF-8) for htmlentities()
echo htmlentities($str, null, "UTF-8");
```

The problem seems to be (according to documentation) that if UTF-8 is not specified, in PHP versions prior to 5.4.0, ISO-8859-1 is the default encoding for `htmlentities`.

If `$str` is UTF8 encoded then it will only work ok in PHP>=5.4.0, where UTF-8 is the default encoding for `htmlentities` if no encoding is specified.